# jQuery trigger mouseenter not working in Internet explorer 8

Tags: jquery

i tried to trigger mouseenter event manually by using $("element").trigger("mouseenter"). it works fine in all the browser except IE8.

```
<html><head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="box" style="border:5px solid red;width:100px;height:100px">
     </div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#box").mouseenter( function(event){
        console.log("mouseenter triggered!!");
      });
      $("#box").trigger("mouseenter");
      //$("#box").mouseenter();
    });
 </script>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: No, i don't get any errors on console. its just that event is not getting triggered.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

IE8 does not have a lot of support for newer versions of jQuery.  I know that jQuery says so but it isn't always true. Try using an older library, before jQuery 1.6.  You could even add a browser detection function to switch between the two libraries.

--edit--
OK, got marked down repeatedly there so let me expand my answer.  I am not suggesting abandoning the newer JQ libraries because that would indeed be stupid.

Test to see if your feature works with the older JQ library.  If it does you will have to try using something like Modernizr or some other kind of detection software to serve the old jQuery library to that browser.  If it doesn't -- and it shouldn't in most cases -- then serve the newer jQuery library.

--edit 2-- and indeed that seemed to solve the poster's problem, eh?

Comment: In my experience, bugs with IE have been fixed in later versions of jQuery. And jQuery 1.8 supports IE8, and has unit tests to ensure that works.

Comment: Dave, you are right. it works with JQuery 1.6. thank you so much.

Comment: IMHO this is a ***VERY*** poor answer. You should not tell the OP to use a version of jQuery that is over 2 years old...